# Not so easy inequality: $(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)\ge8$

Tags: inequality

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be three positive numbers such that $x+y+z=xy+xz+yz$

prove that

$(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)\geq8$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: What is the domain of x,y and z? For natural numbers, the proof is trivial

Answer (score 3):

We may assume that $x,y,z$ are the roots of
$$ q(t) = t^3-st^2+st-p $$
with $x+y+z=xy+xz+yz=s$ and $xyz=p$. If $q(t)$ has three positive roots, $q'(t)$ has two positive roots by Rolle's theorem, hence its discriminant is positive. The discriminant of $q'(t)$ is $4(s^2-3s)$, hence $s\geq 3$. For a given value of $s\geq 3$, the value of $q(t)$ in the greatest root of $q'(t)$ has to be negative. That gives a non-trivial lower bound for $p=xyz\geq 0$:
$$ p\geq \frac{1}{27}\left(9s^2-2s^3-2(s^2-3s)^{3/2}\right)$$
and a lower bound for $(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)=-q(-1)$:
$$ -q(-1) = 1+2s+p \geq \max\left(1+2s,1+2s+\frac{1}{27}\left(9s^2-2s^3-2(s^2-3s)^{3/2}\right)\right).$$
If $s\geq 4$ there is nothing left to prove. If $s\in[3,4]$, we may notice that $\sqrt{s^2-3s}\leq s-2$, so:
$$ -q(-1)\geq 1+2s+\frac{1}{27}\left(9s^2-2s^3-2(s^2-3s)(s-2)\right)= 1+\frac{14}{9}s+\frac{19}{27}s^2-\frac{4}{27}s^3$$
and the last function is increasing over $[3,4]$, with its value at $s=3$ being equal to $8$ as wanted.